# In which direction should a light beam have on the plane $\pi$ for its reflection to go in $v=(1,-1,-1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Im struggling with an exercise that's about projection onto a plane, see below.

In which direction should a light beam have onto the reflection plane $\pi:2x+y-3z=0$ for its reflection to have the direction $(1,-1,-1)$?

My solution is the following:

$Q:=(1,-1,-1)$

$T:=($projection of $\vec{OQ}$ onto plane)

$P:=($reflection of $Q$ onto plane)

The idea I had was simply to project $\vec{OQ}$ onto the plane, which gives me point $T$.

$$\vec{TQ}= \frac{\vec{OQ} \cdot \vec{n}}{|n|^2} \vec{n} = \frac{(1,-1,-1) \cdot (2,1,-3)}{14}(2,1,-3)= (\frac{4}{7}, \frac{2}{7}, \frac{-6}{7})$$

So $$\vec{QT}=(\frac{-4}{7}, \frac{-2}{7}, \frac{6}{7})$$

From here I know that $\vec{OP}$ is the reflection on the backside of the plane with the same direction as the vector I seek. We also know that $\vec{OP}=\vec{OQ}-2\vec{QT}$.

$$\vec{OP}=(1,-1,-1)-2(\frac{-4}{7}, \frac{-2}{7}, \frac{6}{7})=\frac{1}{7}(15,-3,-19)$$

However, this gives me wrong answer. Is this a correct idea? Or is there anything I miss here?

The correct answer is $(-1,-11,5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reflection matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by

$ F = (2 {n n}^T - I_3) $

where $I_3$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, and $n$ is the unit vector normal to the plane of reflection.

In this problem, $n = \dfrac{(2, 1, -3)}{\sqrt{14}} $

Therefore,

$ F =  \dfrac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix} 4 && 2 && - 6 \\ 2 && 1 && - 3 \\ -6 && -3 && 9 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{7} \begin{bmatrix} -3 && 2 && -6 \\ 2 && -6 && -3 \\ -6 && -3 && 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Clearly, $F$ is its own inverse, thus if

$ v = F \ u $, then $u = F^{-1} \ v = F \ v $

Hence, the requested incidence vector is given by

$ u = F \ [1, -1, -1]^T = \dfrac{1}{7} [1, 11, -5]^T $

Hence, $ u $ is along the direction $-[1, 11, -5]^T = [-1, -11, 5]$.

Alternatively, if you want to do it without matrices, then using your notation, let

$ Q = (1, -1, -1) $

And let $O = (0,0,0)$

And let $ \vec{n} = (2,1,-3) $

Find the two components of $\vec{OQ}$.  The projection of $Q$ onto the
normal of the plane is given by

$ \vec{OT} = \dfrac{ \vec{OQ} \cdot \vec{n} }{\vec{n} \cdot \vec{n}} \vec{n} = \dfrac{ (1, -1, -1) \cdot (2, 1, -3)}{(2,1,-3) \cdot (2, 1, -3) } (2, 1, -3) = \dfrac{ 4 }{ 14 } (2, 1, -3) = \dfrac{2}{7}(2, 1, -3)$

The other (perpendicular) component of $\vec{OQ}$ is $\vec{OS}$ which is simply

$ \vec{OS} = \vec{OQ} - \vec{OT} = (1, -1, -1) - \dfrac{2}{7} (2, 1, -3) = \dfrac{1}{7} (3, -9 , -1) $

The reflection of $Q$ is $P$, and is given by

$\vec{OP} = \vec{OT} - \vec{OS} = \vec{OQ} - 2 \vec{OS} $

and this equals,

$\vec{OP} = \dfrac{2}{7}(2, 1, -3) - \dfrac{1}{7} (3, -9, -1) = \dfrac{1}{7} (1, 11, -5) $

Hence, $\vec{PO} = - \vec{OP} $ is along $(-1, -11, 5)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer however, this is to be solved without matrices since matrices are the next chapter in the book. Would you mind explaining what im doing wrong in my solution?

Comment: @uoiu Please check my updated answer.  I've added the vector method.

Comment: There is one step that doesn't makes sense to me, the first step. $\vec{OT}$ shouldn't be the projection of $Q$ onto plane, because you are projecting $\vec{OQ}$ onto the planes normal, so the vector given by that should be $\vec{TQ}$ shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here the normal is $\hat{n}=(2,1,-3)/\sqrt{14}$, the reflected ray is $\hat u=(1,-1,-1)/\sqrt{3}$. Let the incident ray vector be $\hat v$. Then the $\hat n$ is expressed as $$\hat n=\frac{\hat u- \hat v}{|\hat u- \hat v|}= \frac{\hat u-\hat v}{\sqrt{2(1+ \cos \theta)}}=\frac{\hat u- \hat v}{2\cos (\theta/2)},\quad\cos \theta=(\hat u. -\hat v),\cos(\theta/2)= -\hat v.\hat n=\hat u. \hat n.$$ Finally we can write $$\hat v=\hat u-2 (\hat u. \hat n) ~\hat n=\frac{(1,-1,-1)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{2(2-1+3)}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{14}}\frac{(2,1,-3)}{\sqrt{14}}=\frac{1}{7\sqrt{3}}(-1,-11,5).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, do you see what i'm doing wrong in my calculations?